# How to assign 50 X 20 array with 2 X 20 array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I have below code

```
x=zeros(50,20)
for i=1:50
    slect=roulette_select(cprob,pop) # it's a function return 2 X 20 array 
    x[i,:]=slect
end
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to assign two columns to one, exactly as the error message says. You can just assign two rows in the same go (modifying the example by Simon):

```
k = 2

function roulette_select (a, b)
    return ones(k, 20)
end

cprob = 0.5
pop = 1

x = zeros(50, 20)
for i = 1:2:50    # <-- You skip over each second line (25 iterations)
    slect = roulette_select(cprob, pop)
    x[i:i+1,:] = slect    # <--- you have to change two lines (i and i+1) at once
end
```

You can either do this, or if possible modify roulette_select to return a single line at a time, why does it return two?

Answer (score 2):

This may be clearer with a fully self-contained example:

```
k = 2

function roulette_select (a,b)
    return ones(k,20)
end

cprob = 0.5
pop = 1

x=zeros(50,20)
for i=1:50
    slect=roulette_select(cprob,pop)
    x[i,:]=slect
end
```

This code throws the error:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("tried to assign 2x20 array to 1x20 destination")
```

... but if we set `k = 1` in the first line, it runs fine.

The issue is that `x[i,:]=slect` assigns to a 1x20 destination, so it requires a 1x20 array to be supplied.

Comment: it doesn't work to my code because function roulette_select already return ones(2,20) ,I want to do that for 50 times and got array of 50 X 20 @Simon

Comment: In that case, perhaps you will need to run the loop 25 times and assign the first row that is returned from `roulette_select()` to the odd-numbered rows in `x` and the second row to the even-numbered rows, or something like that?